# Failed to load aspnetcorev2.dll hosting ASP.NET Core 2.2 on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64, webdeploy

I am struggling with deploying an ASP.NET Core 2.2 site to Windows 7 SP1 IIS7.5.

The server has dotnet-hosting-2.2.1-win installed. Following are the Programs and Features entries:
[image: Installed Hosting Packages]

Registered IIS modules:
[image]

The application pool is configured in the following way:
[image]

The app pool is used only by one web application and is running under a windows account.

I am deploying an ASP.NET Core 2.2 website using the following publish settings:
[image]

This is the deployed web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\App.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Whatever I do, the app pool will stop and the following error will show up in the Event Viewer:
`The Module DLL C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.`

I tried deploying with:

- Any CPU/x86/x64
- win-x64/win-x86/Portable
- Self-Contained/Framework-dependent
- hostingModel="InProcess"/hostingModel="OutOfProcess"
- Enable 32-bit Applications="true"

Also attempted the following workarounds:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6118
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206

Whatever I do, I can't make the application pool run. Does anyone know what could be causing those problems?

**UPDATE** For some reason even the other IIS sites on .NET Framework that used to work before, now can't start with the same error - `The Module DLL C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.`

**ANSWER** After a lot of digging it turned out that the installer for the hosting bundle failed to download Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable. That is why all websites stopped working. I installed it manually and resintalled the hosting bundle and everything worked.

Answer (score 19):

After a lot of digging it turned out that the installer for the hosting bundle failed to download Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable. That is why all websites stopped working. I installed it manually and resintalled the hosting bundle and everything worked.

Comment: You absolute legend! Installing the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable worked for me too, i'd love to know why? I've checked my dev env and that doens't have it either but doesn't have the same problems.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue, but this didn't solve it. Tried installing Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable and 2017 -- I also tried dotnet-hosting-2.2.2 but I still have the same error as you did initially.

Comment: @zed , is this affecting all IIS sites or only your .NET Core site?

Comment: @NikolayArhangelov, correct. All websites are being affected, not only core websites. If I uninstall core hosting bundle, it goes back to normal. I had posted details here but it is marked for deletion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258935/the-net-core-hosting-bundle-makes-all-iis-websites-crash-alterative-for-hosti

Comment: Microsoft did mention the installation of Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem on a Windows Server 2012 R2.
I tried to reinstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable, but the error was still there.
What fix the problem for me :

1. Uninstall Runtime & Hosting Bundle and Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable
2. Run the following command to check and repair file system :

   sfc /scannow
3. Run the following command to check the Windows image for any corruption and to perform a repair automatically :

   dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
4. Run Windows Update and install all updates (this can take a while)
5. Install Runtime & Hosting Bundle from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Answer (score 1):

download Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=52685

and reinstall hosting bundle.